# Should I expect this code to block? Any way to make it block?

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

I wanted to call an async method from top level code and ran across code similar to that shown below as a solution for how to do it. It appears that while it does call DoSomething(), it doesn't block and the code below continues to run before DoSomething() returns.

```
// code...

(async () => await DoSomething())();

// more code...
```

After further consideration, I believe I do understand why it would work this way. I suppose I could wrap the rest of my code below in a .then() call to get the expected behavior though that doesn't seem ideal.

Is it possible to write a synchronous method `CallSynchronously(asyncMethodToRun)` to run an asynchronous method synchronously?

Note: I haven't found a question/answer on SO specifically saying how to do what I'm asking for, nor have I seen an answer definitively saying it can't be done. But if anyone would like to close this question as a duplicate and point to some other answer that gives alternative solutions that's totally cool with me. All I ask is that if the answer you point to doesn't *specifically* say what I asked for can't be done, that you make a point of telling me in a comment if that's the case. Because I will troll the hell out of you if you don't, lol. :)

Comment: Async operations are out of sync; that's it, they can't be coerced into acting sync.
You can put an `await` before the iife though.

Comment: @xxh Thanks, I understand your first statement. Not sure what you mean about the second though... not even sure if iffe is a typo?

Comment: Yes, corrected.

Comment: @xxh iife? I'm even more confused, lol

Comment: Oh wow, sorry; here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE.

Comment: @xxh Ah okay. So I'm like the guitarist who knows exactly what a dominant sharp 9 flat 13 chord sounds like and has played it numerous times but never had any clue it was called that. So thanks for filling in my knowledge gap there. But to your statement that "you can put an `await` before the iife though, it sounds like I can't since I'm in top level code, right? And I don't think I would need the iife if I weren't in top level code. :/

Comment: Oh, this is top-level code!? Yeah no, time to whip out that big `.then` call *:)* There is a proposal for top-level await, just waiting for it to finish and roll out. Actually, I'm updating my answer right now.

Comment: @xxh cool, thx for clarifying that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to force an async operation to run in sync.

If this were possible, the main thread would never get anything done.

Think of getting a mouse click event, waiting for it is an inherently async operation.

If such an operation were to block the thread, the click itself could never be received, as the main thread is blocked!

The key idea is that an async operation will just *happen*, it doesn't particularly care about the execution flow of your program, and neither does your program, this is why async/await exists.

Sometimes we must look at what async/await in JavaScript really is: a nice syntax for what would otherwise be callbacks.
(besides the stack traces, it's equivalent to using `.then`)

In reality, async functions ***synchronously*** return a promise object.

The promise object is *resolved* asynchronously.

```js
// code...

(async () => await DoSomething())();

// more code...
```

If you want `more code` to wait for the call to `DoSomething`, then simply remove the iife, like so:

```js
// code...

await DoSomething();

// more code...
```

Alternatively, if there is extra code in the block, you can use the `await` operator before the iife:

```js
// code...

await (async () => await DoSomething())();

// more code...
```

(if there is extra code in the function, then likely you can reduce it to just brackets)

If this is top-level code, you can wrap the entire thing in the iife:

```js
// code...

(async () => {
    await DoSomething();

    // more code...
})();
```

This is by far, the simplest way to write top-level async code, and what I have done personally.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I can't do what you're suggesting because I can't use await in top level code. I will say one problem I'm having is that when I export, I can't seem to figure out how to export an asynchronous function. I get errors. I believe I have seen others doing it though. So that's a separate question I need to ask, but unless you have more to suggest... it sounds like the answer for this question is simply that it cannot be done.

Comment: Updated. Do you need to export something after the async function call?

Comment: I just meant that my "final" export default (or whatever you would call it... the one in my App.js) is not currently async. And when I tried to make it async I got an error. I will ask another question about that later if I don't figure it out on my own. I've been a full stack Microsoft shop developer for many years now but just started getting into RN a couple months ago because, well, Xamarin sucks for the same reason WPF sucked.

Comment: Funnily enough, I've never even touched RN, yet I understand the entire core JS language. Never needed to know RN to answer this, not sure if it even needs the tag.

Comment: True, it's more of a javascript issue which I meant to tag the post with initially but didn't (just added it though). Glad you took interest in the post anyway. :)